# Limit of ratio of definite integrals, Conditional expectation of Beta distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, beta-function

I'm trying to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{a,b \to \infty}\frac{\int_{\frac{a}{a+b}}^1 t^{a}(1-t)^{b-1} dt}{\int_{\frac{a}{a+b}}^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1} dt}-\frac{a}{a+b}.$$

---

I think the limit should exist, and should be $0$, but could not formally show that is the case.

And what if we have $a\rightarrow \infty, b>0$, or $b\rightarrow \infty, a>0$? Does the limit exist? Is it $0$?

Any suggestion helps.

Notice that the expression has the interpretation of $$\mathbb{E}\left[t-\frac{a}{a+b} \Big| a,b, \text{ and } t-\dfrac{a}{a+b}>0\right]$$ where $t|a,b\sim Beta(a,b)$. i.e., the conditional expectation of $t$ given $t$ is above the mean of the $Beta$ distribution.

May assume $a/(a+b)$ stays constant if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If $a/(a+b)=\tau\in(0,1)$ is fixed, then we let $a=\lambda\tau, b=\lambda(1-\tau)$ with $\lambda>0$ and ask for $$L=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{\Phi(\lambda,\tau,0,-1)}{\Phi(\lambda,\tau,-1,-1)},\qquad\Phi(\lambda,\tau,\alpha,\beta)=\int_\tau^1 t^{\lambda\tau+\alpha}(1-t)^{\lambda(1-\tau)+\beta}\,dt.$$

The asymptotics of $\Phi$ as $\lambda\to\infty$ can be analysed using [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method): the integral is of the form $I(\lambda)=\int_a^b f(t)e^{\lambda g(t)}dt$ with $g(t)$ having the maximum at $t=a$, $g'(a)=0$ and $g''(a)<0$; in this case, the method yields the asymptotics $I(\lambda)\asymp f(a)e^{\lambda g(a)}\sqrt{\pi/(-2g''(a)\lambda)}$ (notation: here $F(\lambda)\asymp G(\lambda)$ means $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty}F(\lambda)/G(\lambda)=1$). In our case $$g(t)=\tau\log t+(1-\tau)\log(1-t),\\g'(\tau)=0,\qquad g''(\tau)=-\frac{1}{\tau(1-\tau)},\\\Phi(\lambda,\tau,\alpha,\beta)\asymp\tau^{\lambda\tau+\alpha+1/2}(1-\tau)^{\lambda\tau+\beta+1/2}\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2\lambda},$$ making $L=\tau$ obvious. The cases of fixed $a$ or $b$ could also be handled by (other variations of) this method, but there are also elementary means (integration by parts and $\int_\tau^1=\int_0^1-\int_0^\tau$).

Answer (score 0):

Concerning
$$I=\dfrac{\int_{\frac{a}{a+b}}^1 t^{a}\,(1-t)^{b-1}\, dt}{\int_{\frac{a}{a+b}}^1 t^{a-1}\,(1-t)^{b-1}\, dt}=\frac{\text{num}}{\text{den}}$$ we have, after simplifications
$$\frac{\text{num}}{ab}=\Gamma (a+2) \Gamma (b)-(a+1) \Gamma (a+b+1) B_{\frac{a}{a+b}}(a+1,b)$$
$$\frac{\text{den}}{a+b}=a (a+1) \Gamma (a+b)+\Gamma (a+2) \Gamma (b+1)+ $$ $$ \left(\frac{a^a b^b}{ (a+b)^{a+b}}-(a+b)
   B_{\frac{a}{a+b}}(a,b+1)\right)$$ Assuming $\frac a{a+b}=k$ that is to say $b=\frac{a}{k}-a$, *I do not see what to do beside numerical experiment*.

Trying for $a=10^4$ and a few $b$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b & I-\frac a{a+b}\\
 1000 & 0.00217116 \\
 2000 & 0.00270260 \\
 3000 & 0.00293954 \\
 4000 & 0.00303978 \\
 5000 & 0.00306629 \\
 6000 & 0.00305040 \\
 7000 & 0.00300948 \\
 8000 & 0.00295378 \\
 9000 & 0.00288959 \\
 10000 & 0.00282091 \\
 11000 & 0.00275029 \\
 12000 & 0.00267938 \\
 13000 & 0.00260925 \\
 14000 & 0.00254059 \\
 15000 & 0.00247383 \\
 16000 & 0.00240921 \\
 17000 & 0.00234689 \\
 18000 & 0.00228690 \\
 19000 & 0.00222925 \\
 20000 & 0.00217391
\end{array}
\right)$$